# How to open urls to X domain with my app, and pass it as argument?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an app that takes an URL to X domain, makes a get with Jsoup, scraps some content, and the present that content. I've already done that with an EditText on my app, but what i want now is that the app can be selected as an app to open the url from other apps(You know, when the app shows an URL, you click, and then a prompt asks which app would you want to use), and then pass that url as the parameter of the EditText, doesn't matter if directly start execution, or if just paste the url on the EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want now is that the app can be selected as an app to open the url
>   from other apps

Add `intent-filter` with `BROWSABLE` category in AndroidManifest:

```
<activity ...>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" /> 
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

> pass that url as the parameter of the EditText, doesn't matter if
>   directly start execution, or if just paste the url on the EditText

Call `getIntent().getData()` in BROWSABLE Activity to get provided Uri to open or show in `EditText` :

```
// prepare URL
Uri dataUri = getIntent().getData();
URL webUrl = new URL(dataUri.getScheme(), 
                     dataUri.getHost(), 
                     dataUri.getPath());
```